# Converting blog (blogger/blogspot) backup to latex?

Tags: lyx, import, xml

It would save me quite a bit of work if I could find a way to convert the blogspot backup of my blog to Latex. Easy web searches aren't showing me much.

the backup file starts with an xml declaration that includes more than two links, so I can't post it verbatim, but it references this atom stylesheet:

```
xml-stylesheet href="(https://) www . blogger . com / styles / atom . css"
```

and these xmlns schema:

```
xmlns:gd='(http://) schemas . google . com / g / 2005' 
xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0' 
xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss'
```

among some other stuff that I don't have enough reputation points to post. (Had to mangle the above to post even those.)

Does anyone know of a quick way to do such a conversion so that I can avoid learning more about xml transformations than I really want to learn, or the alternative of a lot of copy/paste/reformat/import images/etc.?

Comment: try this http://www.elml.org/website/en/html/output_latex.html

Comment: Technical remark to your post: With 4 spaces at line start you can add code (I just did it in your poting). Can you now check the spaces in your code? I think, they should also be changed, but I was not sure, what I should change (e.g. the bracket around the https...)

Comment: Those spaces were added because I don't have enough reputation to post more than two functioning links in a question. When I get enough rep, I could insert the actual preamble, but it looks like I may have an answer already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps. https://github.com/arpruss/blogger-to-latex

"This script, based on Andrew Heiss's Blogger to InDesign script,
converts Blogger Atom XML to nice LaTeX."

Comment: I tried my own blogger site, almost perfect. The config file needs to be slightly better edited.

Comment: On Debian Wheezy, I had to install two or three packages, and latex is not lyx, but texlive does a conversion. Heh. I have no idea what I'm doing, but I got a reasonable PDF out of it.

Comment: The packages I installed (from the debian repositories instead of CTAN and CPAN, because that's the Debian way), were texlive-base,
libconfig-general-perl,
libxml-libxml-simple-perl, and
libxml-simple-perl. The rest I already had.

Comment: Made a subdirectory, copied the backup into the subdirectory, along with the header.tex included with Alexander Pruss's version of the tool, moved to the subdirectory, edited the header.tex, and used pdflatex file.tex to produce a nice pdf. Not really what I wanted, but getting what I wanted is my homework. Thanks.